# Using regular expression as action names in struts

Tags: regex, struts2

This code works for me as expected :

```
<action name="{paramOne}/{paramTwo}/details" 
class="myactionclass"  
method="execute"> 
      <result name="success">/mypage.jsp</result>
</action>
```

I'm able to retrieve the values of paramOne and paramTwo in my action class.
But is it possible for paramOne in request url to only have the values which i predefine already? Like, can I write some regular expression or do something else so that my paramOne has only one of the values which i had already predefined. If paramone has a value other than permitted values, the action class should not be called.

```
<action name="/{type}/{value:.+}/list"
```

I also want to know what does ".+" in the above expression mean? if i want my paramOne to only have values true or false.. can i achieve it as follows?

```
<action name="/{type}/{paramOne:(true|false)}/list"
```

Comment: First, you should enable a pattern matcher then write a regex.

Answer (score 0):

https://struts.apache.org/docs/wildcard-mappings.html#WildcardMappings-AdvancedWildcards

> From 2.1.9+ regular expressions can be defined defined in the action name.
>   [...]
>   The regular expression can also be in the form `{FIELD_NAME:REGULAR_EXPRESSION}`. The regular expression is a normal Java regular expression.

Comment: Yes, the regular expressions are working. But when I use '*' in my regex it throws an null pointer exception in java/util/treemap.java.

Comment: And I want my paramTwo to have 10 permitted values. Should I have to specify each of the 10 values in regex as : value1 | value2 | .. and so on? Can i use some kind of variable to store the permitted values instead?